# R package installation: ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib'

Tags: r, igraph

I am trying to install an R package from source:

[igraph](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/igraph/igraph_1.2.4.tar.gz)

Here is my command:

```
install.packages('igraph_1.2.4.tar.gz', repos = NULL, type="source")
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/8.2.0'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/8.2.0'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib'
ld: library not found for -lgfortran
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [igraph.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘igraph’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/igraph’
* restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/igraph’
```

Comment: If this is on macos you might need to install xcode: `xcode-select --install`

Comment: I followed the instructions here and it resolved my issue: https://medium.com/biosyntax/following-up-library-dependency-when-compiling-r-packages-89f191b9f227

Answer (score 4):

After the fresh installation of R, I had to manually change the `FLIBS` variable in `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/etc/Makeconf` to point to the gcc libraries.

Also, the post here helped: https://medium.com/biosyntax/following-up-library-dependency-when-compiling-r-packages-89f191b9f227

In detail the post suggests to change the following entries in `Makeconf` (make sure you use the correct version on your system):

```
# Use Homebrew gcc for OpenMP support
CC = gcc-8
# CC = clang # Original setting
...
# Use Homebrew gcc for OpenMP support
CXX = g++-8
# CXX = clang++ # Original setting
...
# Ask R to find the Homebrew copy of gcc
FLIBS = -L/usr/local/lib/gcc/8/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0/8.1.0 -L/usr/local/lib/gcc/8 -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm
# The original one
# FLIBS =  -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15/6.1.0 -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm
```

No restart of Rstudio is required after the changes are made.

Comment: Been wrestling with this for a while now since I wanted to use the Fortran in Homebrew, finally solved thanks to this! I didn't need to change the `CC`/`CXX` settings for `igraph` but imagine they can be useful for `OpenMP` as in the post.